# Custom Attribute Values not Prompted when Generating CSR with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I am trying to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) using OpenSSL, and I want to include custom attributes in the CSR such as **`EGSSerialNumber`**, **`OrganizationIdentifier`**, **`OrganizationalUnitName`**, **`OrganizationName`**, **`Location`**, **`Industry`**, and **`InvoiceType`**. To achieve this, I have modified the **`config.cnf`** configuration file to define these custom attributes in the **`req_distinguished_name`** and **`my_custom_attributes`** sections.

However, when I run the OpenSSL command to generate the CSR, I am not prompted to enter values for these custom attributes. Instead, only the default fields like "Country Name," "State or Province Name," "Locality Name," "Organization Name," "Organizational Unit Name," "Common Name," and "Email Address" are prompted.

and i have also used this command "openssl req -new -sha256 -key privateKeyyy.pem -config openssl.cnf -subj "/EGSSerialNumber=INM111018MN/OrganizationIdentifier=311012244170003/OrganizationalUnitName=IT/OrganizationName=uuu/Location=Riyadh/Industry=Tech/InvoiceType=1100"
"
the result is :
req: Skipping unknown subject name attribute "EGSSerialNumber"
req: Skipping unknown subject name attribute "OrganizationIdentifier"
req: Skipping unknown subject name attribute "OrganizationalUnitName"
req: Skipping unknown subject name attribute "OrganizationName"
req: Skipping unknown subject name attribute "Location"
req: Skipping unknown subject name attribute "Industry"
req: Skipping unknown subject name attribute "InvoiceType"
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIG3MF8CAQAwADBWMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKA0IABEb0lqD1jolv8aAjTfFa
S7Qt35TfSkoYFOzY2soNbCN96Yo2oqXMZbM3uBP9EUKcKnqbAEM0DUfq3qQbbv+R
I0GgADAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNIADBFAiAOJQxGWICHTQpxqikcOD1MD2iFXwjelLrA
vXBV4ayw5gIhAOUtFedeAij1q8HQkWjxVDMauHTDBbqBtIQ4MsMEaUvF
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

**Expected Behavior:** I expect that when generating the CSR, OpenSSL should prompt me to enter values for the custom attributes defined in the **`config.cnf`** configuration file, such as **`EGSSerialNumber`**, **`OrganizationIdentifier`**, **`OrganizationalUnitName`**, **`OrganizationName`**, **`Location`**, **`Industry`**, and **`InvoiceType`**.